# How to avoid shinytest ambiguities with navbarMenu entries having identical names?

Tags: r, shiny, automated-tests, shinytest

This is my very simple Shiny `app.R`. As you see, there are sub-menu entries having the same names under the two top menu entries:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  navbarPage("App", id = "nav",
    navbarMenu("Top 1", # id = "top1",
      tabPanel("Sub 1", "Top 1, Sub 1"),
      tabPanel("Sub 2", "Top 1, Sub 2")
    ),
    navbarMenu("Top 2", # id = "top2",
      tabPanel("Sub 1", "Top 2, Sub 1"),
      tabPanel("Sub 2", "Top 2, Sub 2")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I can run this app and access all submenu entries just fine using `shiny::shinyAppDir(".")`.

However, when recording tests going through all tabs using `shinytest::recordTest(".")`, the recorded script looks something like this:

```r
app <- ShinyDriver$new("../../")
app$snapshotInit("mytest")

app$setInputs(nav = "Sub 2")
app$setInputs(nav = "Sub 1")
app$setInputs(nav = "Sub 2")
app$snapshot()
```

You see the problem immediately: from the calls, it is unclear which of the top-menu entries I chose (for the record, I chose Top 1, Top 2, Top 2).

How can I deal with this without renaming the sub-menu entries? I tried adding an `id` to the `navbarMenu`s as you can see above, but that resulted only in

> Tabs should all be unnamed arguments, but some are named: id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found this:

> **value** The value that should be sent when `tabsetPanel` reports that this tab is selected. If omitted and `tabsetPanel` has an `id`, then the title will be used.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/tabPanel.html

So one solution is:

```r
library(shiny)
ui <- basicPage(
  navbarPage("App", id = "nav",
    navbarMenu("Top 1",
      tabPanel("Sub 1", "Top 1, Sub 1", value = "top1/sub1"),
      tabPanel("Sub 2", "Top 1, Sub 2", value = "top1/sub2")
    ),
    navbarMenu("Top 2",
      tabPanel("Sub 1", "Top 2, Sub 1", value = "top2/sub1"),
      tabPanel("Sub 2", "Top 2, Sub 2", value = "top2/sub2")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

which gives

```r
app <- ShinyDriver$new("../../")
app$snapshotInit("mytest")

app$setInputs(nav = "top1/sub2")
app$setInputs(nav = "top2/sub1")
app$setInputs(nav = "top2/sub2")
app$snapshot()
```